how do I stop my elements moving around upon zoom?
Im learning how to code, and self-learning, and I've researched this the best I can but not sure which direction to look in and I can't find a resolution. I was wondering how I can stop my elements from moving about on zooming in and out on  desktop. This is the code so far, I'm learning python and Flask as well so some CSS is in jinja. Dont judge I couldn't think of a project so I went with an elon musk fan website lol.


function toggleDropdown(dropdownId) {
  document.getElementById(dropdownId).classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menus if the user clicks outside of them
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
      var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content');
      dropdowns.forEach(function(dropdown) {
          if (dropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
              dropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
      });
  }
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "main";
  src: url('../Fonts/Mainfont.otf') format('opentype');
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

/* Video background */
#fullscreen-video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -10;
}

#fullscreen-video-container video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* IMG */
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 290px;
  top: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* General Dropdown Button Styles */
.dropbtn {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

/* Dropdown Content Styles */
.dropdown {
  position: relative; /* Keep dropdowns relative */
  display: inline-block; /* Aligns buttons inline */
}

/* Specific positioning for each dropdown */
.dropdown-odyssey {
  margin-left: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
  top: 30px; /* Adjust vertical position */
  margin-left: 790px;
}

.dropdown-more {
  margin-left: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
  top: -9px; /* Adjust vertical position */
  margin-left: 950px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show dropdown */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Searchbar */
#searchbar {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 1070px;
  top: 30px;
}

input {
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.footer p {
  font-family: main;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
}

intro{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 300px;
  
}

h1{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 840px;
  top: 190px;
  font-family: main;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

p1{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 700px;
  top: 250px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 600px;
  text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
  
}

.footer p {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: main;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 630px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, , user-scalable=no">
    <title>Muskiverse: Exploring the Genius of Elon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='CSS/Homepage.css') }}">
   
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="container">
        <div id="fullscreen-video-container">
            <video autoplay loop muted>
                <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/Videos/Background.mp4') }}">
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="img">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/Images/logo2.png') }}" alt="Logo">
        </div>

        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/Homepage.html">Home</a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Sign In</a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Elon Musk</a>
            <a href="/Timeline">Through the Times</a>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown dropdown-odyssey">
            <button onclick="toggleDropdown('dropdown1')" class="dropbtn">Elon's Odyssey</button>
            <div id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">NeuralLink</a>
                <a href="#">Space X</a>
                <a href="#">Tesla</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown dropdown-more">
            <button onclick="toggleDropdown('dropdown2')" class="dropbtn">More</button>
            <div id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">DOGE</a>
                <a href="#">BLOGS</a>
                <a href="#">Forums</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="searchbar">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        </div>
    </nav> 
  
    <nav class="footer">
        <p>MUSKIVERSE MMXXIV</p>
    </nav>
  

    <div class="intro">

        <h1>MUSKIVERSE</h1>
        <P1>Step into the Muskiverse, a dedicated space for fans and enthusiasts of Elon Musk! Here, we celebrate the visionary behind revolutionary companies like Tesla and SpaceX, exploring his groundbreaking innovations and audacious goals. Join us for the latest news, insightful articles, and a vibrant community that shares your passion for the future Musk envisions. Together, let’s dive into the world of technology, space exploration, and the relentless pursuit of a better tomorrow!</P1>
      </div>
   

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>




What do you mean by elements moving about? HTML is supposed to be somewhat dynamically flexible.

when i zoom out on the homepage all my elements fly to the left such as text and navbar is smaller. and on another webpage I've not put the code up for all the text and images are just in completely different positions. how do I make these static so it looks the same upon zooming in and out?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a very poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out LearnLayout.com
